# Should I define both _WIN32 and _WIN64 in 64bit build?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-c++, configuration, 32bit-64bit

When we add a 64bit configuration from a 32bit project that has already existed, Visual Studio copies the 32bit configurations by default. VS even copies *_WIN32*
All my 64bit projects define also *_WIN32* now, despite they(64bit PEs) never can run on 32bit Windows. It is very uncomfortable to me.

I'd like to remove the *_WIN32* if it doesn't have any problem. I'm not sure about that.
Is it okay if I remove the *_WIN32* definition?

Comment: Is it OK? Don't know. What is your objective?

Comment: You just want to know if it is OK to remove, but you are not providing enough detail about where the application is supposed to execute (will it be running on 32bit? yes? no?) What problem would removal solve?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

_WIN32 doesn't mean what you think it does.  It means "I am using the Windows API".  The 32 postfix was added back in the days of Windows NT 3.1 to make it distinct from the 16-bit API that was used in Windows version 3.  This term has fallen out of favor because of the bitness problem.  You can see this at stackoverflow.com, the [win32] tag takes you to [winapi].

Don't remove it, you are using the Windows API.

Answer (score 58):

The documentation for the [predefined macros](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay.aspx) says:

> **_WIN32:** Defined for applications for Win32 and Win64. Always defined.
>
> **_WIN64:** Defined for applications for Win64.

So not only should `_WIN32` *always* be defined, it does not cause any problem in 64-bit applications. Therefore, I'd suggest you don't remove it.

Answer (score 14):

You should never define either of them.

The toolchain (compiler + system headers) will define them as appropriate.

Comment: I think this is technically incorrect - the MSVC compiler always defines _WIN32, it does not define WIN32 unless it is told to by its input e.g. a /DWIN32 option.  Many projects (tell the compiler to) define WIN32, but that is the project's decision, not the compiler's.

Comment: @Spike0xff: Good point, not all the system macros are necessarily predefined in the compiler binary itself.  Hopefully this edit made the answer more accurate.  (on the other hand, the question and answer were about `_WIN32` not `WIN32`, and about `_WIN64` not `WIN64`)

Comment: good point about the OP! Great edit, I reversed my vote. (incidentally props on your profile statement ;-)

Comment: The ACCU has a free article that reviews these predefined macros (with leading underscore) as well as the manually defined counterparts (without a leading underscore).  See [QM Bites: Understand Windows OS Identification Preprocessor Macros](https://accu.org/journals/overload/24/132/wilson_2223/).

Answer (score 6):

> _WIN32：Defined for applications for Win32 and Win64. Always defined.
>
> _WIN64：Defined for applications for Win64.

More detail: [Predefined Macros](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay.aspx) .

To put it simply, WIN32/_WIN32 is used to tell whether you are using Windows(For crossing system application), while _WIN64 is used to tell the compiling environment is x86 or x64.

If you want to know whether your application is running under Windows x64, you should use Windows API [IsWow64Process](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684139.aspx) .