# opencv3.2 compilation with debug mode x64 not possible on visual studio 2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv, debugging, visual-studio-2017

While working on opencv3.2 installation, as in [these steps](http://www.learnopencv.com/install-opencv3-on-windows/) and the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43786856/how-to-can-i-install-configure-opencv3-2-0-with-visual-studio-2017), after generating opencv correctly with CMake, I couldn't execute the All build - debug x64 because the only option I found from Debug configuration manager are: Win32 or empty. (I didn't find x86) That means **Step 6.2** fails.

I don't know the reason because I followed the steps exactly as they are and my windows is 64 bits and I even tried creating a C++ and verified that is Debug mode x86 exists.

What should I do?  as the build in debug failed (with 1 success and 112 fails)

Thank you for your help.

Comment: `x86` means 32bit. So does Win32.

Comment: IIRC, with the MSVC generator you can either get a 32bit or 64bit project generated, not both. e.g. with MSVC 2013, if I run cmake with `-G "Visual Studio 12 2013"`, I get a 32bit project, if I run with `-G "Visual Studio 12 2013 Win64"` I get a 64bit project. Don't have MSVC 2017 to test it with, but I'd expect it to behave similarly.

Comment: I run it from cmake gui not command line

Comment: So instead of writing it on command line, you select it with a combo box in the Tools>Configure dialog. Doesn't really make a difference.

Comment: @Sarah M, Active solution platform is different from the project platform, do you select the correct drop down item?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17601305/whats-the-relation-of-win32-project-name-in-visual-studio-to-x86-or-x64-platf? Based on the screen shot in Step 6.2, it was the solution platform, not the real project platform.

Comment: @DanMašek I re-configured and generated the project using Visual Studio 14 2017 Win64, now I find x64 in debug. before, I selected Visual Studio 14 2017 without precising Win64. Otherwise, how it is different active solution platform from active project plateform? changing one changes the other (I tested that)

Comment: @SarahM Yep, that's what I suspected. Regarding the second part, you'll have to ask Jack Zhai, who mentioned it. TBH, ever since I, years ago, made all my projects use a common cmake-based buildsystem, I haven't had to muck around with most of those configuration dialogs in MSVS :)

Comment: @DanMašek, You could get some information which shared the differences between them here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9225017/active-solution-platform-vs-project-platform-vs-platform-target. Just to make this issue clearly, what about this issue now? Could you debug your app now?

Comment: The issue is resolved. As I explained in my last comment. :) Thank you.

Comment: @Sarah M, Glad to know that it has been resolved, if so, would you please post the solution as an answer(not a comment)? So you could mark it as the answer and close this case, and it would help other community members who meet the same issue find the answer easily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I re-configured with cmake and generated the project using `Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64`, now I find x64 in debug and my problem is resolved. Before, I selected Visual Studio 15 2017 without precision Win64.